# Why doesn't my interface support comparison?

Tags: f#

This code does not compile:

```ml
type IFoo =
  inherit System.IComparable<IFoo>

let m : Map<IFoo, int> = Map.empty
```

Since `IFoo` does not implement `comparison`

Why is `System.IComparable<'t>` insufficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the non-generic version of `IComparable` that is required for this:

```
type IFoo =
  inherit System.IComparable

let m : Map<IFoo, int> = Map.empty
```

Comment: Why? ..........

Comment: Well, that question is better addressed to the F# designers.

Comment: There's language suggestion on allowing `IComparable<'t>` to satisfy constraint https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/816